# notifications not getting grouped

Tags: android, android-notifications

I an a noob in android, I am trying to show notification of the push notifications I receive. Every time I receive a push notification a new notification is created in the notification bar, even if an exisiting one is present. I want them to be grouped together.

This is what I am currently doing

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String ticker, String title, String msg, int icon, Intent intent)
  {
    int notificationId = 1;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int pendingNotificationsCount = AppName.getPendingNotificationsCount() + 1;
    AppName.setPendingNotificationsCount(pendingNotificationsCount);
    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setWhen(when)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
    .setNumber(pendingNotificationsCount);
//This prints the count correctly.... 
    Log.d("Snehan", "Message built with Count "+pendingNotificationsCount);
    Notification notif = mNotifyBuilder.build();
    notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notif);
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong here or missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Android updated the library since I last used it. But the logic is still the same. You need to save whatever the notification id was or at least give it a name you can track and check if it exists. More info can be found in the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Managing). Below is a snippet from what I mean.

> To set up a notification so it can be updated, issue it with a notification ID by calling NotificationManager.notify(ID, notification). To update this notification once you've issued it, update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same ID you used previously. If the previous notification is still visible, the system updates it from the contents of the Notification object. If the previous notification has been dismissed, a new notification is created instead.

The docs have everything you need so no need for me to write the code for you :) Hope that helped.

**Edit**:

Ok, so I recommend you adda a dummy icon just to see what that does. I also recommend instead of chaining all that stuff only chain the text stuff. This way you can debug a bit easier. Try to follow the doc a bit more closely. I don;t really see anything wrong with your code, but obviously something is causing the issue.

**Edit 2**

So it seems the icon was the problem. I've had this issue before, which is why I mentioned to add that explicitly. Hopefully when someone encounters issues with notifications please make sure you have an icon!!

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am currently doing in the code I have pasted in my question, using same notification id, but still I am getting a new one :(

Comment: Do me a favor and try adding a dummy icon to your notification. I had problems with that in the past. Try adding one.

Comment: Icons is coming fine, no issues with that,

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the icon on the notification though. Could you also post the the intent values are for that parameter for your method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60774/discussion-between-snehan-solomon-and-andy).

Comment: Glad I could help :) Accept the answer if your problem was solved. Good luck.